# Angular mat-menu is closing on checkbox selection, how to avoid

Tags: angular, angular-material

It is nested mat-menu and has checkboxes to select multiple items.

Upon clicking checkbox it closes the menu. It should remain intact to select multiple items.

> "@angular/core": "^17.1.1",
>
> "@angular/material": "^17.2.0",

```
<mat-menu #actionsMenu="matMenu" id="actions-menu">
  <button [matMenuTriggerFor]="selectColMenu" id="select-columns" mat-menu-item>
    <mat-icon>arrow_left</mat-icon>
    <span class="small">Select Columns</span>
  </button>
</mat-menu>

<mat-menu #selectColMenu="matMenu">
  @for(c of columnsCopy; track c; ) {
  <button class="form-check" (click)="$event.stopPropagation()" (keydown)="$event.stopPropagation()" mat-menu-item>
    <input
      class="form-check-input mx-1"
      type="checkbox"
      [value]="c"
      (click)="$event.stopPropagation()"
      [checked]="checkedColumns.has(c.key)"
      (change)="toggleColumns(c.key); $event.stopPropagation()"
      (keydown)="$event.stopPropagation()"
    />
    <label class="form-check-label small" style="margin-top: 2px"> {{ c.title }} </label>
  </button>
  }
</mat-menu>`
```

Comment: I think the css may be to blame here. If you click anywhere outside those buttons, the menu will close. Just a guess since the repro in the answer does work correctly.

Comment: (change)="toggleColumns(c.key); is the culprit here

Comment: Can you post the previous code for toggleColumns and how you fixed it as the answer? It would be helpful for anybody coming to this in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I am unable to replicate the issue, please find below a working example. Maybe something is missing, please share back the stackblitz with the issue replicated!

```
<button [matMenuTriggerFor]="actionsMenu" id="select-columns">Opener!</button>

<mat-menu #actionsMenu="matMenu" id="actions-menu">
  <button [matMenuTriggerFor]="selectColMenu" id="select-columns" mat-menu-item>
    <mat-icon>arrow_left</mat-icon>
    <span class="small">Select Columns</span>
  </button>
</mat-menu>

<mat-menu #selectColMenu="matMenu">
  @for(c of columnsCopy; track c; ) {
  <button
    class="form-check"
    (click)="$event.stopPropagation()"
    (keydown)="$event.stopPropagation()"
    mat-menu-item
  >
    <input
      class="form-check-input mx-1"
      type="checkbox"
      [value]="c"
      (click)="$event.stopPropagation()"
      [checked]="checkedColumns.includes(c.key)"
      (change)="$event.stopPropagation()"
      (keydown)="$event.stopPropagation()"
    />
    <label class="form-check-label small" style="margin-top: 2px">
      {{ c.title }}
    </label>
  </button>
  }
</mat-menu>
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/6agygp?file=src%2Fexample%2Fmenu-nested-example.html,src%2Fexample%2Fmenu-nested-example.ts)